# Which is a better way to access Context in instrumented unit tests?

Tags: android, androidx, android-context, ui-testing, instrumented-test

Which of the following is more recommended to access `Context` in instrumented unit tests: using `ApplicationProvider` or `InstrumentationRegistry`?

```kotlin
val context: Context = ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext()
```

```kotlin
import androidx.test.platform.app.InstrumentationRegistry

val context: Context = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().targetContext
```

I know `androidx.test.InstrumentationRegistry` is deprecated, but `androidx.test.platform.app.InstrumentationRegistry` is not.

Comment: Have you found an answer for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can either use `androidx.test.platform.app.InstrumentationRegistry` or  `android.support.test.InstrumentationRegistry`, according to your respective Android SDK version, and get the `Context` by:

```
Context context = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().getTargetContext();
```